# Visual Studio - Custom Build Validation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I need to write a simple method that will be invoked at compile time and that will generate a build error if some conditions are not met.

Is it possible to do this via some particular attribute?

Comment: That's what Roslyn Analysers are for. _But_: I wouldn't consider any of that "simple".

Comment: See: [How to write a Roslyn Analyzer - .NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/), [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix - C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) and/or [Getting Started with Roslyn Analyzers - Visual Studio (Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022)

Comment: _"if some conditions are not met"_ - what (type of) conditions are we talking about, exactly?

Comment: I posted an answer, does the pre build event and condition meet your requirement? If not, please clarify more about your issue. :)

Comment: Hi update of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether the prebuild event and condition is what you want:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'net' != 'net1'">
    <Exec Command="exit 1" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The key part is:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'net' != 'net1'">
    <Exec Command="exit 1" />
  </Target>
```

Official documents:

[How to: Use Build Events in MSBuild Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-use-build-events-in-msbuild-projects?view=msvc-170)

[MSBuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022)